# Oxidation state of sulfur in H2S2O5

Tags: oxidation-state

How can I find the oxidation state of sulfur in $\ce{H2S2O5}$ using its structure?

This is the structure of $\ce{H2S2O5}$:

[image: structure of H2S2O5]

Comment: Consider every bond and which way it is polarized.

Comment: S-S bond is not polarized. Both sulphur will have different oxidation states

Comment: How can I find the oxidation of sulphur @Mithoron using the structure? Are there any rules to be followed?

Comment: It looks like homework... Hmm,  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35343/oxidation-of-carbons is analogical

Comment: @Mithoron: if I take $x$ as the oxidation state of sulphur, $2+2x-10=0$, $x=4$. But Wikipedia says 5 and 3.

Comment: Then don't take $x$ as the oxidation state of sulphur. I mean, you seem to dislike that answer with 3 and 5. Why, really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the states of oxygen and hydrogen to know the oxidation state of sulphur.
[image]

Comment: While technically correct and nicely painted, this answer provides little explanation as to its conclusion. How do we know that O is -2 and H is +1, really? Are they always this way? Well, good like trying to apply that to $\ce{H2O2}$.

Comment: Electronegativity. What is the possible oxidation states for oxygen and hydrogen?
Oxygen is the more electronegative element of the compound. So, his charge will be -2, and the hydrogen is bonded with the oxygen so his charge will be +1. The sulphur charge is consequence.